# catch plural route in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, routes

in expressjs, I use routing like below;

```
app.use('/game', require("./routes/game"));
```

in the file `/routes/game.js`

```
const express = require('express');  
var router = express.Router();

router.get("s", function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("GAME LIST");
})
router.get("/:gameurl", function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(`GAME: ${req.params.gameurl}`);
})

module.exports = router;
```

I'd like to catch both `/games` and `/game/wow`
How can I manage to handle both routes separately?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You want routes for `/games` and `/game/wow`.  What's the problem with just using `app.get('/games',...)` and `app.get('/game/wow',...)`?  Or you can put the route for `/game/wow` in the `/game` router as `router.get('/wow',...)`.

Comment: I just want to catch both route in `./routes/game.js` file. second part, `app.get('/:gameurl')`, works great! but first part should be like append "/game + s"  and catch `/games` url.. am I clear now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want both `/games` and `/game` to go to your router, but not any other top level paths, then there are a number of ways to specify it.  You can see them described [here in the doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use).  For example, you could use a regex or pass multiple strings.  In this case, I'll show you the multiple strings:

```
 app.use(["/game", "/games"], require("./routes/game"));
```

For the route path, you can pass a single string, a path pattern (an Express subset of regex), a regex, or an array that contains any combination of these.

If you want to be able to tell the difference between `/game` and `/games` in your router, then you will have to examine `req.originalUrl` to see which one caused it to go to your router which seems to me to kind of defeat part of the purpose of routing in the first place.

Thus, sending two separate top level paths to the same router and routing them differently inside the router is not a design that works well with Express.  Personally, I'd either change my path design so this doesn't happen or use two routers as that fits better with the router mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
app.use('/', require("./routes/game"));
```

in the file /routes/game.js

```
const express = require('express');  
var router = express.Router();

const base = '/game';

router.get(`${base}s`, function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("GAME LIST");
})
router.get(`${base}/:gameurl`, function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(`GAME: ${req.params.gameurl}`);
})

module.exports = router;
```